# Cannot successfully implement singleton

Tags: programming, c++, adafruit, arduinoisp, feather

I have spent the better part of today trying to figure out why I can't get this to work...

I have this project where, because of previous design considerations, have implemented a singleton class that initializes a bunch of separate sensors in this system that I am running.

The system was originally built for the Particle Boron, but now I am trying to make it work with the Adafruit Feather M0, so I have had to refactor several things and omit lots of lines of Particle RTOS specific things.

However, in doing this, I find that my singleton class no longer works.

**Sensors.h:**

```
.
.
.

class Sensors{

    static Sensors *instance;

public:
    static Sensors *getInstance() {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = new Sensors;
        }
        return instance;
    }

}

private:
    Sensors();

.
.
.
```

**Sensors.cpp:**

```
.
.
.

Sensors::Sensors() : dht22(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE) {
#ifdef PLATFORM_ID
    sensorLog("app.Sensors");
#endif
}

.
.
.
```

**main.ino:**

```
.
.
.

// Sensors
Sensors *Sensors::instance = nullptr;
Sensors *allSensors = allSensors->getInstance();

void setup(){

.
.
.
```

As I try to compile this with ArduinoISP, no matter what I try, I get the following error:

```
sketch/main.ino.cpp.o: in function `Sensors::getInstance()':
sketch/lib/Sensors/src/Sensors.h:23: undefined reference to `Sensors::Sensors()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
[Error] Exit with code=1
```

I have tried things like changing the line

```
instance = new Sensor;
```

to

```
instance = new Sensor();
```

making the `instance` public, changing the Sensor constructor, but all of this to no avail. Could this be a compiler issue? Why would this work on a Particle board, but not an Adafruit Feather M0?

Comment: is the cpp in the same folders as the ino?

Comment: Unlike RTOS, Arduino is single threat and no OS, there is really not have any benefit to implement singleton in Arduino environment...

Comment: `private: Sensors()` is outside your class - and your class lacks the required `;` at the end of it. Your code is uncompilable as it stands.

Comment: @Majenko, the constructor is used only in `getInstance`. it can be private and is declared there. the compiler founds it. the error is at linking

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when referencing classes from multiple files, remember to put at the top of your header file (ending in .h) `#pragma once` on files that get referenced more than once!

Edit1: Also after you declare your class you need to specify where your static variable will be stored.
After the class declaration write:

type *Class::variable;

To declare the static variable.

For example:

```
#pragma once
//#includes

class Screen
{
protected:
  static void (*StateMachineStep)(int);
  static SSOLED *oled;
  static Player *player;

public:
  Screen() {}

};

void (*Screen::StateMachineStep)(int);
SSOLED *Screen::oled;
Player *Screen::player;
```

Edit2: formatting

Answer (score 0):

Singletons aren't a thing in Arduino. Sure, you *could* do it, but in general you'd make a class then instantiate a global object for that class. Most often that global object is instantiated in the library itself, not the sketch.

Unless you're using an advanced chip with an RTOS (such as ESP32) and making use of the threads of that RTOS heavily there is no benefit to having a singleton.

But to answer your actual question: it's probably because you are trying to use the `Sensors()` constructor at a time before the compiler knows what the `Sensors()` constructor is. You would have to add some form of forward declaration so that the compiler knows what you mean when you talk about the `Sensors()` constructor.  In general a simple:

```
class Sensors;
```

at near the top of your header before the class is actually defined can help in these situations;

Comment: Or the OP can simply move the private contructor from the private section to above the public section. Then it should be private (because there is no modifier above and private is the default) and declared before its usage.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer, ordering of class members in the class declaration doesn't matter

Comment: @Juraj You are right. Please, forget what I said. I'll leave the comment as an example of ignorance ;-) and to help other not to have the same misconception. Now, I think the main problem is that the `getInstance` method is implemented in the class definition and the constructor is not (just declared). So, probably it helps also if we move the implementation of the`getInstance()` into the cpp file an leave only the signatur declaration in the hpp file. Or is there a reason why this would not work?

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer, I think the cpp is not compiled, because it is in some folder ignored by IDE

Comment: @christopolise Are you still with us?  What Juraj mentioned in the answer of my last comment sounds good.  The CPP file might not be compiled. Did you investigate in that direction? Juraj mentioned that in a comment for the OP, but I have to apollogize for not having recognized it.

Comment: @Juraj Yes, I agree with you. Your idea is also underlined by the fact that, the code worked on a RTOS system, but not after using the ADUINO IDE. I hope the OP is still here, as I'm interested in the final answer ;-)